# How to handle network error in grpc-node that happens after streaming has started?

Tags: node.js, streaming, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm having issue getting correct error handling for streaming from upstream server when server disconnects. I handle `status`, `end`, `error` events on the stream returned from method call but if I stream some large response and break network connection between my app and upstream server in the meantime, nothing happens. No event gets emitted, my end API client times out (I do `server <-> express app <-> api client`) but I suspect streams/resources are not cleaned up on my server side. 
What's proper way of detecting and handling that?

Answer (score 0):

When processing a request on a server, the `call` or `stream` object that is passed to the server's handler function will emit a `"cancelled"` event if the request/stream is terminated unexpectedly.